# Google Map API key error "Your site URL to be authorized"

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-api

I have searched many links and read documents related to google api key, but every time I am getting the only error of `Your site URL to be authorized`

I am creating a **PhoneGap hybrid application** where I am not sure if which URL I have to pass to google api key referrer so I am stuck here

What I am using for google script is:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Updated**

I have already created Browse Key using google console but now What I have to pass in referrer link ( ? ) while I am creating a cordova application

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Leave it blank
2.You need to enable the google maps api for your project.

Comment: After Leaving it blank `Google Maps API error: ApiNotActivatedMapError https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#api-not-activated-map-error`

Comment: You are getting further.

Comment: Enable: Google Maps JavaScript API - Done, but dont understand whats wrong with this now, in my device it always showing 'Something Went Wrong - See the javascript console for technical details'

Comment: And whats inside the console log? Screenshot?

Comment: I am working with hybrid application so i need all these API for ios and android and javascript and I have enabled all that API's from `Google Maps APIs` and now its **working fine** with my android device for now

Answer (score 3):

I Dont know if this will help anyone but I spent a good hour trying to figure out this problem and ended up realizing I had the wrong API enabled.
You need Google Maps JavaScript API enabled.Also sometimes you need to specify https.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to enable the google maps api for your project.
2. if your API key have no limitation and it still not work - trying to add `signed_in=true` to url. It helps for me.

Comment: nope. not working for me

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the current URL loading the Maps JavaScript API has not been added to the list of allowed referrers. Please check the referrer settings of your API key in the Cloud Console. (source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error)

Go to the Google Cloud credentials page to add your website url: https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/google/maps-apis/credentials

1. Select the API key that you want to set a restriction on. The API
   key property page appears.
2. Under Key restrictions, set the following restrictions:

   - Application restrictions:

     1. To accept requests from the list of website that you supply, select HTTP referrers (web sites) from the list of Application restrictions.
     2. Specify one or more referrer web sites. For example, `*.google.com` accepts all sites ending in `google.com`, such as `https://developers.google.com`.
        Note: file:// referers need a special representation to be added to the key restriction. The `file://` part should be replaced with `__file_url__` before being added to the key restriction. For example, `file:///path/to/` should be formatted as `__file_url__//path/to/*`. After enabling `file:// referers`, it is recommended you regularly check your usage, to make sure it matches your expectations.
3. Save your changes
4. You must include an API key with every Maps JavaScript API request. In the following example, replace YOUR_API_KEY with your API key.

   `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>`

(source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#restrict_key)