# Website open in browser but not work in WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have tried many times to open this link in webview (https://www.prpal.com/#/) but all time failed

This link is working in all browsers in Android or iOS.

Please someone help me to open this link in webview in Android studio

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler 
    handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }
});
webView.loadUrl("https://www.prpal.com/#/");
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

}

Comment: What's the error you getting?

Comment: only blank (white Screen)

Answer (score 11):

I've tested it and I found the issue, you are missing [`setDomStorageEnabled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDomStorageEnabled(boolean))

> Sets whether the WebView will enable smooth transition while panning or zooming or while the window hosting the WebView does not have focus. If it is true, WebView will choose a solution to maximize the performance. e.g. the WebView's content may not be updated during the transition. If it is false, WebView will keep its fidelity. The default value is false.

New code is :

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wb_test);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler
                handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.prpal.com/#/");
```

This is the output :

[image]

Comment: Dear thankyou so much for this

Comment: @FahadSharif When an answer solves your problem, don't forget to mark it as accepted :)

Comment: helped me in 2021

Answer (score 0):

when i tried to load your URL in webView it was giving me this error

```
 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(58)] "Google Maps JavaScript API error: RefererNotAllowedMapError

    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-not-allowed-map-error

    Your site URL to be authorized: https://www.prpal.com/#/", source: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB46qkQ0B22hLbZW6HX2e8llY2wzHeDqzk&libraries=places (58)


2019-04-17 18:54:17.202 4186-4186/com.psycho.webviewdemo I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190415/r20190131/show_ads_impl.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source:  (0)
```

goto this Question [[Google Map API key error "Your site URL to be authorized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987037/google-map-api-key-error-your-site-url-to-be-authorized) ] for that